# Using Google Protocol Buffer - How to define fields in .proto file

Tags: c++, data-structures, protocol-buffers

I am working with [Simulation Open Framework Architecture SOFA](https://www.sofa-framework.org/) (`C++` language) and my goal is setup some communication type between some sofa origin native data to other external application. With this order I am using ZeroMQ to transport the sofa data to a python external application.

In SOFA (`C++`) I have the following `instrumentData` structure

```
#include <sofa/core/behavior/BaseController.h>
#include <sofa/defaulttype/VecTypes.h>

// To Quat datatype
#include <sofa/defaulttype/Quat.h>
using sofa::defaulttype::Quat;

using std::string;

namespace sofa
{

namespace component
{
namespace controller
{
struct instrumentData
{
  typedef sofa::defaulttype::Vec3d Vec3d;
  Vec3d pos;
  Quat quat;
  int btnState;
  float openInst;
  bool blnDataReady;
};
}
}
}
```

I am trying a data communication of these below data member `instrumentData` structure via zmq, and to serialize / unserialize these data I am using [Google Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) with the order of my python destiny data application understand and interpret it the content of the instrumentData data members structure. Currently this data members structure arrive to your destiny but in binary format/content.

Google Protocol Buffer require describe a protocol in a format build inside `.proto` file extension, in which is necessary

> you'll need to start with a .proto file. The definitions in a .proto file are simple: you add a message for each data structure you want to serialize, then specify a name and a type for each field in the message.

How to can I represent in my `instrumentdata.proto` file, the following fields: `pos`, `quat`, `bool` ... ?

```
typedef sofa::defaulttype::Vec3d Vec3d;
Vec3d pos;

using sofa::defaulttype::Quat;
Quat quat;

bool blnDataReady;
```

Currently, [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#whats-generated-from-your-proto) is not clear about of how to should I define the fields in relation to Vectors and other data types like `Quat` (quaternions) which are SOFA native.

`Vec3d` and `Quat` is composed of some elements such as follow:

```
void ZMQServerComponent::instrumentDataSend(instrumentData a)
{
    a.pos = sofa::defaulttype::Vec3d(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    a.quat = defaulttype::Quat(1.0f, 1.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Is possible define as [enumerators](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum)?

**UPDATE**

For the moment my tentative `instumentdata.proto` file which I am building according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple) is:

```
sintax = "proto3";
message InstrumentData {
    // enum Pos {}
    // enum Quat {}
    int32 btnState;
    float openInst;
    bool blnDataReady
}
```

Although I have some doubts in relation to this single protocol definition

Comment: You probably need to have some additional `.proto` files (message descriptions) to describe `Vec3D` and `Quat` types. Can you show your attempts for the `.proto` files please? Anyways a mapping layer to your native structures will be necessary, you can't represent those native structures in a direct manner. And of course it's possible to define _enumerations_ in the protocol buffer language. Did you even bother to read their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#enum)?

Comment: @TheDude In first instance thanks for the hints. 
It's not that I have not researched or read, is that I already have some proto file version, just that I don't think so that this was sufficiently well builded. Can you see my **UPDATE** please?

Comment: @TheDude sure, I've read the enums documentation and I have clear their application case, my question were oriented in relation to how to can I apply the enum concept in relation with my `Vec3d` and `Quat` data types struct. I really really sorry if my question degrade the stackoverflow philosophy and I take your comments and suggest of a better way :) And of course. I will have that really research a lot about of my question specifically. Best Regards

Comment: These aren't representable as arrays of _enums_. As mentioned you have to resemble those types as separate `message` definitions. Good you provided your `.proto` language attempts now though.

Comment: @TheDude Ok thanks!.  I'll follow research and document me about of how to represent in my `.proto` file this `SOFA`  data types  struct which are not include inside `C++` stack

Answer (score 3):

From the description, `Vec3d` and `Quat` are not enumerations, but structures, which you would describe as separate `message` types, e.g.

```
message Vec3d {
  float x = 1;
  float y = 2;
  float z = 3;
}
```

and

```
message Quat {
  float a = 1;
  float b = 2;
  float c = 3;
  float d = 4;
}
```

These message types can then be used in the `InstrumentData` message type

```
message InstrumentData {
  Vec3d pos = 1;
  Quat quat = 2;
  int32 btnState = 3;
  float openInst = 4;
  bool blnDataReady = 5;
}
```

Comment: As for my understanding from the Sofa docs `Vec3D` rather resembles to an array of points, looks like you're missing one more level of indirection there. Also `Quat` seems to be a typo, the original type is named `Quad` actually.

Comment: Also if you look closer at the `Quad` definition there aren't `float` values actually, but `PointID` values, which finally turn out to be `unsigned int` `typedef`'s.

Comment: According to [Vec.h](https://github.com/sofa-framework/sofa/blob/master/SofaKernel/framework/sofa/defaulttype/Vec.h#L868), I would say it's just a vector of 3 doubles.

Comment: Ah, it means a geometrical vector. In that case you're right.

Comment: And looking at [Quat.h](https://github.com/sofa-framework/sofa/blob/master/SofaKernel/framework/sofa/defaulttype/Vec.h#L868), it's float or double.

Comment: Anyway, the main point is, he should define sub message types for use in the main structure.

Comment: You put the wrong link for `quad.h`, but in general I think we state the merely same problem solution.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the `required` fields I introduced in my answer. I've been working with older versions of _protobuf_, seems that `optional` is the default though. I don't know anything about that _sofa_ stuff, but that's bit a question of semantics then. According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362671/will-you-stay-on-after-the-tipping-point) I'd suppose your answer will be upvoted 1st in favor to mine ;-) ...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you have to resemble the types from your framework to reasonable message definitions and provide a mapping layer to translate the generated stuff to your frameworks native classes.

`Vec3D` and `Quad` aren't `enum`s in your framework and shouldn't represented as such in the protocol buffer messages definitions accordingly.

Your `.proto` file should rather look like (not tested yet):

```
message Vec3D {
    required float x = 1;
    required float y = 2;
    required float z = 3;
}

message Quad {
    required float a = 1;
    required float b = 2;
    required float c = 3;
    required float d = 4;
}

message InstrumentData {
    optional Vec3D = 1;
    optional Quat = 2;
    optional int32 btnState = 3;
    optional float openInst = 4;
    optional bool blnDataReady = 5;
}
```